# Why Does "Step BY Step" Have No Indefinite Article?

Tags: indefinite-article

We use **by** to mean something each or separate (*e.g.,* one **by** one, step **by** step, [electoral votes **by** state](https://projects.economist.com/us-2020-forecast/president), [wine consumption **by** country](https://www.economist.com/node/21011894/2...%3C/p%3E%3C/blogs/newsbook/2010/10/aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?page=132&id=20141228-0), *etc.*), and these **by**s suppress the following nouns' indefinite articles. For example, we say "electoral votes by state" rather than "electoral votes by *a* state" or "electoral votes by *each* state," nevertheless the *state* is even countable. Why must we omit these indefinite articles in front of the nouns right next to these **by**s?

Comment: Those nouns tend to be "uncountable(which gives a unique meaning)", especially before "a preposition". e.g. pose a threat(possible), the species are *under threat of becoming extinct* **(no article - mass noun - unique meaning )**; moreover, those phrases( if countably used) may sound weird to a native speaker 'cuz they could sound wrong. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but did you mean those nouns especially after "a preposition?" So are the nouns used in this way considered as temporarily uncountable nevertheless originally countable and hence suppresses preceding articles?